# How to get an array with the contents of a directory in Octave?

Tags: octave

How can I get the contents of a directory containing XML files in Octave and store the file names in an Array?

Comment: @Andy Thanks, please post this as an answer that I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `dir`, `ls`, `readdir` and `glob`. If you want to search a pattern I would suggest glob:

```
fns = glob ("*.xlm");
```

which will return a cell array with relative (to `pwd`) filenames.